# Create Annotation instance with defaults, in Java

Tags: java, annotations, instantiation

How can I create an instance of the following annotation (with all fields set to their default value).

```
    @Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME )
    public @interface Settings {
            String a() default "AAA";
            String b() default "BBB";
            String c() default "CCC";
    }
```

I tried `new Settings()`, but that does not seem to work...

Comment: instantiate an annotation with method references: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68837852/2158288

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You cannot create an instance, but at least get the default values

```
Settings.class.getMethod("a").getDefaultValue()
Settings.class.getMethod("b").getDefaultValue()
Settings.class.getMethod("c").getDefaultValue()
```

And then, a dynamic proxy could be used to return the default values. Which is, as far as I can tell, the way annotations are handled by Java itself also.

```
class Defaults implements InvocationHandler {
  public static <A extends Annotation> A of(Class<A> annotation) {
    return (A) Proxy.newProxyInstance(annotation.getClassLoader(),
        new Class[] {annotation}, new Defaults());
  }
  public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
      throws Throwable {
    return method.getDefaultValue();
  }
}

Settings s = Defaults.of(Settings.class);
System.out.printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", s.a(), s.b(), s.c());
```

Comment: It is wrong that "You cannot create an instance" of an annotation! 
You can create an instance of an Annotation. You only need to create a class implements java.lang.annotation.Annotation and the concrete annotation interface (for example Settings), and then you can create an instance of this class.
See my answer for more details

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Technically you create an instance of a subclass of the annotation, just as does the proxy at runtime.

Comment: @akuhn, you might also add @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") to the factory method "of"; while typecast with suppressed warning doesn't look clean, but I like your solution as it really is typesafe and allows to safely use IDE's refactoring features.

Comment: Thanks! Works nicely but for that it crashes when there are primitive members without defaults. Using com.google.common.base.Defaults you might do:
        return method.getDefaultValue() != null ? method.getDefaultValue() :
                Defaults.defaultValue(method.getReturnType());

Answer (score 41):

To create an instance you need to create a class that implements:

- [`java.lang.annotation.Annotation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html)
- and the annotation you want to "simulate"

For example:
 `public class MySettings implements Annotation, Settings`

But you need to pay special attention to the **correct** implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` according to the `Annotation` interface.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html

If you do not want to implement this again and again then have a look at the [javax.enterprise.util.AnnotationLiteral](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/javax/enterprise/util/AnnotationLiteral.html) class.
That is part of the CDI(Context Dependency Injection)-API.
[(@see code)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/javax/enterprise/util/AnnotationLiteral.java)

To get the default values you can use the way that is described by akuhn (former known as: Adrian).
`Settings.class.getMethod("a").getDefaultValue()`

Comment: Beautiful. Honest. Really beautiful. I tried it myself and it deserves to become the approved solution for this question.

Comment: Do you get it right that this solution requires to implement each “method” of the annotation manually?

Comment: @Adrian: right, you have to implement the Interface that is defined by the Annotation. -- In you case you will need the methods `a()`, `b()` and `c()`

Comment: At least using Eclipse, you'll have to provide the fully qualified name of your annotation to implements. That reduces the compile-error to a warning.

Comment: `java.lang.Annotation` does not exist, should this be `java.lang.annotation.Annotation`? And if so, what is the sense in implementing it explicitly, as it is the super-interface of any annotation anyway.

Comment: @Vampire: you are right: it is `java.lang.annotation.Annotation` (I fixed it)

Comment: @Vampire: And it is also right, that it is *not required* to name `Annotation` in the list of implemented interfaced explicit. Anyway I made it explicit in order to mark the implementation class as class that is different to the other once.

Answer (score 28):

I compile and ran below with satisfactory results.

```
class GetSettings {
    public static void main (String[] args){
      @Settings final class c { }
      Settings settings = c.class.getAnnotation(Settings.class);
      System.out.println(settings.aaa());
    }
}
```

Comment: Local classes, I keep forgetting about them, nice hack!

Comment: Actually this one looks probably better than the current accepted answer as it keeps the static typing all the way. Whereas the current accepted answer relies on method names in a String.

Comment: @SaM not quite, the accepted solution calls `getDefaultValue` on the method object passed to the proxy. This is the same way annotation are implemented by Java itself, so it is just as "type safe" as yours. (The initial code examples that use a string to select the method are only used to illustrate the principle.)

Comment: @akuhn This is still better. No misspelling the method name. No need to cast the DefaultValue to String.

Comment: This is great - but doesn't work if the retention policy is SOURCE :/

Answer (score 3):

had the same issue, i solved it as follows.

```
public static FieldGroup getDefaultFieldGroup() {
    @FieldGroup
    class settring {
    }
    return settring.class.getAnnotation(FieldGroup.class);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is alternative solution, if you can afford to change the body of `Settings` class:

```
@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME )
public @interface Settings {
        String DEFAULT_A = "AAA";
        String DEFAULT_B = "BBB";
        String DEFAULT_C = "CCC";

        String a() default DEFAULT_A;
        String b() default DEFAULT_B;
        String c() default DEFAULT_C;
}
```

Then you can simply reference `Settings.DEFAULT_A` (yes, a better name would help!).

Answer (score 1):

If used with a method:

```
@Settings
public void myMethod() {
}
```

Now your annotation is initialized with default values.

Answer (score 0):

This works with Sun/Oracle Java 5,6,7,8: (but could potentially break with Java 9 due to the sun classes involved). 
//edit Just verified that this still works with OpenJDK 9b59.

```
package demo;

import sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser;

import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class AnnotationProxyExample
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.printf("Custom annotation creation: %s%n", 
                createAnnotationInstance(Collections.singletonMap("value", "required"), Example.class));

        System.out.printf("Traditional annotation creation: %s%n", 
                X.class.getAnnotation(Example.class));
    }

    private static <A extends Annotation> A createAnnotationInstance(Map<String, Object> customValues, Class<A> annotationType)
    {

        Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();

        //Extract default values from annotation
        for (Method method : annotationType.getDeclaredMethods())
        {
            values.put(method.getName(), method.getDefaultValue());
        }

        //Populate required values
        values.putAll(customValues);

        return (A) AnnotationParser.annotationForMap(annotationType, values);
    }

    @Example("required")
    static class X
    {
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
    @interface Example
    {
        String value();
        int foo() default 42;
        boolean bar() default true;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Custom annotation creation: @demo.AnnotationProxyExample$Example(bar=true, foo=42, value=required)
Traditional annotation creation: @demo.AnnotationProxyExample$Example(bar=true, foo=42, value=required)
```