# Enum static arrays and annotation values confusion

Tags: java, enums, annotations, netbeans-7

I have enum:

```
public enum Scope {
    USER, GLOBAL;

    public static final Scope[] TRANSIENT = {};
    public static final Scope[] USER_OVER_GLOBAL = {GLOBAL, USER};
    public static final Scope[] GLOBAL_OVER_USER = {USER, GLOBAL};
}
```

and annotation:

```
public @interface Config {
    public Scope[] load() default Scope.GLOBAL_OVER_USER; // Can't use this defval

    public Scope[] save() default Scope.USER;
}
```

Why I can't use static arrays as default values for annotation's property? My NetBeans 7.3 Beta tell me there is required `Scope` but found `Scope[]` - as you can see this not true. Is there a NB's or Java 7 related confusion?

Comment: Are you sure that error is occurring on the line illustrated? Because your code as shown should fail on the line below it.

Comment: @Perception: this is annotation, so `USER` is treated as `{USER}` and it's not a mistype. Problem is with using static hand-made values for annotation's defaults.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `Scope[] GLOBAL_OVER_USER` is not all constant. (Yes, the array itself is constant, however you can change the contents of it e.g. `GLOBAL_OVER_USER[0] = GLOBAL;`.

A workaround is to initiate the array directly in the annotation declaration:

```
public Scope[] load() default {USER, GLOBAL};
```

Comment: I know this workaround, but then how to get default value for this annotation property without its instance?

Comment: Well, you don't have to. By just adding `@Config` (or @Config(save=Scope.GLOBAL) ) the annotation's `load` value will keep it's default value.

Comment: Of course, but imagine case when you don't annotate field to imply annotation defaults.

Comment: [There](http://stackoverflow.com/a/613469/854291) is a way for getting annotation's defaults.