# Guice multiple annotations

Tags: java, guice

I have an interface called `StatsStore`. I have 2 implementations of this store. An in-memory and an SQL implementation called `InMemoryStatsStore` and `SqlStatsStore`. In order to inject them I've create 2 annotations `@InMemoryStore` and `@SqlStore`. the injections are:

```
bind(StatsStore.class)
    .annotatedWith(InMemoryStore.class)
    .to(InMemoryStatsStore.class);

bind(StatsStore.class)
    .annotatedWith(SqlStore.class)
    .to(SqlStatsStore.class);
```

Now I want to add a new layer of annotation to separate between `InMemoryStringStore` and `InMemoryNumberStore` but I can't add more than one annotation to the binding lines e.g. the following does not compile:

```
bind(StatsStore.class)
    .annotatedWith(InMemoryStore.class)
    .annotatedWith(NumberStoreAnnotation.class) // using named doesn't work as well
    .to(InMemoryNumberStore.class);
```

How can I add more than one annotation without using a single named one which would be quite complicated the more layers I add to it?

The other solution I had in mind is Injecting twice:

```
bind(StatsStore.class)
    .annotatedWith(InMemoryStore.class)
    .to(InMemoryStatsStore.class);

 bind(InMemoryStatsStore.class)
    .annotatedWith(NumberStoreAnnotation.class)
    .to(InMemoryNumberStore.class);
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Amit said, you can't have more than one @BindingAnnotation apply to any given injection. Internally, Guice works like a `Map<Key, Provider>` where a Key is a possibly-parameterized class with an optional single annotation instance. However, because these are *instances*, you're welcome to [create your own instantiable annotation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations#binding-annotations-with-attributes) that works the way `Named` works.

```
@Inject @InMemoryStore(NUMBER) StatsStore inMemoryNumberStore;
@Inject @SqlStore(STRING) StatsStore sqlStringStore;
// or
@Inject @Store(dataType=NUMBER, backend=SQL) sqlNumberStore;
```

The annotation must have the fields defined like so. (If you have one element named `value`, you can omit the property name [per JLS 9.7.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.3).) Equal annotations are defined [as in the `Annotation.equals` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
public enum DataType { NUMBER, STRING; }
public enum Backend { SQL, IN_MEMORY; }

@BindingAnnotation @Retention(SOURCE) @Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD })
public @interface Store {
  DataType dataType();
  Backend backend();
}
```

That works nicely for `@Provides`, when you can invoke the annotation  the same way you inject it, but how can you create a factory method for instances like `Names.named`? For that, you'll need to do one of the following:

1. [Create an anonymous implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7067833/1426891), with accessors for each attribute as well as correct implementations of `equals` and `hashCode`. Note that the `hashCode` contract is [much stricter than for `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html#hashCode()), but you can get compatible implementations from [Apache annotation utils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/AnnotationUtils.html) or similar libraries.
2. Use [AnnotationLiteral](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/javax/enterprise/util/AnnotationLiteral.html), which provides `equals` and `hashCode` implementations for arbitrary subclasses.
3. Use [Google Auto](https://github.com/google/auto) or a similar code generator to generate code for a compatible implementation for you. Familiarity with this type of solution is particularly useful for Android and other memory-constrained environments for which reflection is slow, though such environments usually preclude you from using Guice. (`@Qualifier` annotations work the same way in other JSR-330 compatible dependency injection frameworks, though, including Dagger.)

---

If the above seems a little complicated, or if you want more complex logic than Guice's map-based implementation can accomplish, one alternative is to add a layer of indirection that you control:

```
public class StoreStore {
  @Inject Provider<InMemoryNumberStore> inMemoryNumberStoreProvider;
  // ...
  // You can also inject the Injector to call getInstance with a class literal.

  public StatsStore getStore(DataType dataType, Backend backend) {
    // This can also be a switch or any other sort of lookup, of course.
    if (dataType == NUMBER && backend == IN_MEMORY) {
      return inMemoryNumberStoreProvider.get();
    } // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation and solution.

Comment: A nice alternative to actually implementing your annotation is just using an `@Provides` method.

Comment: @Tavian: Yup! Mentioned above ("that works nicely...").

Answer (score 1):

You [can't do that](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations):

> `@BindingAnnotation` tells Guice that this is a binding annotation. **Guice will produce an error if ever multiple binding annotations apply to the same member**.

You could use named bindings instead, or you should consider redesigning your solution.

Comment: Can I add multiple names and not just one long name? I want to avoid, if possible, from having names like `states_tore.in_memory.number`...