# Java: How to safely initialize an annotation default instance field

Tags: java, annotations

Expanding on this question: [Create Annotation instance with defaults, in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266903/create-annotation-instance-with-defaults-in-java)
I am trying to add a default annotation instance as a field on the annotation:

```java
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class AnnoTester {

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE })
    public static @interface Anno {
        Anno DEFAULT = annotation(() -> {
            @Anno
            class Default {}
            return Default.class;
        }, Anno.class);

        String s() default "s";
    }

    @Anno(s = "T")
    public static class TestClass {}

    private static <T extends Annotation> T annotation(Supplier<Class<?>> supplier,
        Class<T> annotationClass) {
        return supplier.get().getAnnotation(annotationClass);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Anno.DEFAULT.s()); // NullPointerException if removed
        System.out.println(TestClass.class.getAnnotation(Anno.class).s());
    }
}
```

Running this gives the desired response of `s` and `T`. However if I remove the reference to `Anno.DEFAULT` in `main()` the code fails to initialize the annotation (stack trace below).

In this case, the annotation proxy created behind the scenes seems to be missing `annotationType()`.

Is there a way to fix this without moving `DEFAULT` outside the annotation declaration?

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy1.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:1044)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:1030)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser$1.run(AnnotationParser.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser$1.run(AnnotationParser.java:304)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.annotationForMap(AnnotationParser.java:304)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:294)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:121)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:73)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3997)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3986)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3869)
    at AnnoTester.main(AnnoTester.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.reflect.Method.getName()" because "method" is null
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:61)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy1.annotationType(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:123)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:73)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3997)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3986)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3869)
    at AnnoTester.annotation(AnnoTester.java:25)
    at AnnoTester$Anno.<clinit>(AnnoTester.java:11)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: There’s some pretty complex interactions regarding class initialization here, which feels like a code smell to me.  Is it really necessary to keep `DEFAULT` inside Anno?

Comment: In general, keeping constants related to a type within that type has benefits. No need for pseudo-namespace naming, and harder to miss when refactoring the main type, such as a move or rename.

Comment: My fallback is to have a non-instantiable nested class implementing the annotation with a static final reference to its annotation `Anno.Default.INSTANCE`

Comment: I agree that the constants should be with the type to which they pertain, but this is a special case.  I think your fallback is the best alternative.  It’s still pretty readable and shouldn’t present a challenge during refactoring.